# Using keyup to count characters in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I completely understand the method of using `.bind('keyup', function() { });` to count characters in a `textarea` or `input`, but I've attempted to do a `keydown` function so you can see the results AS you're typing, versuses, holding down a letter on your keyboard and the count not updating until AFTER you've released the key.

```
var input = $('textarea#input');
$('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);

input.bind('keydown', function() {
    $('span#character-count').text(input.val().length + 1);
});
```

My current method is flawed:

- when you select all and hit delete, the count is messed up.
- it requires +1 to show a live view

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rdvR7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest that an accurate count on keyup is better even if it is momentarily wrong while a key is held down, because in practice I think users don't often need the same character repeated so they don't tend to hold a single key down, and it keeps the code simple. But if you want keydown...

> *"it requires +1 to show a live view"*

I assume you realise that that is because the current value of the field during processing of the keydown event doesn't include the change associated with the keystroke - if it did you couldn't cancel the keydown event without having to undo the change.

A simple way to work around that is to delay updating the count until after the keydown event has finished, perhaps like this:

```
var input = $('textarea#input'),
    count = $('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);

input.bind('keydown', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       count.text(input.val().length);
    },4);
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/rdvR7/2/

Note that the user can add or remove text without triggering a keyboard event at all (through drag'n'drop or cut/paste).

Answer (score 0):

Bind "keyup" event when user select text in textarea:

```
var input = $('textarea#input');
$('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);

input.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    $('span#character-count').text(0);
    input.select( function () {
        input.bind('keyup', function(e) {
            $('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);
        })
    });
    $('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/glenswift/SEBLD/1/

You can also combine bindidng "keydown" and "keyup":

```
var input = $('textarea#input'),
    firstInput = true;
$('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);
input.bind('keydown, keyup', function(e) {
    $('span#character-count').text(0);
    $('span#character-count').text(input.val().length);
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/glenswift/L6DR8/1/

Comment: Note that this will bind more and more select handlers in response to every keydown event, and in turn bind more and more and more and more keyup handlers in response to every select event. (The actual result visible on the page will be the same since all the handlers will do the same thing, but still...)

Comment: Sorry, but I badly understand what you mean. Please, explain what are you meaning saying "since all the handlers will do the same thing, but still" and i try to solve this problem.

Comment: Anyway, i update answer with another method, hope it helps you

Comment: I mean that on first keydown a select handler will be bound, then on next keydown a second select handler will be bound in addition to, not replacing the previous one. Then on next keydown a third select handler will be bound, and so on. Then on select _all_ of these select handlers will execute. Your keyup handlers have a similar problem, because they too are bound from inside an event handler. If you add an alert() inside your select handler and test by typing several characters before selecting text you'll see...